# HTML required functions with javascript which required function doesnt work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Can anyone help me with this required function doesnt work. i am uploading a picture in my html/php web page and before i upload a picture i set a dropdown option which is to upload or not, and this is my code:

```
<script>
    function papeles()
    {
        var x = document.getElementById('tagoan1').value;

        if (x == "YES")
        {
            //  alert('aaaa');
            $('#imgInp').addClass("required");
            $('#imgInp').removeClass("hidden");
            $('#blah').removeClass("hidden");
        } else
        {
            //alert('bbbbb');
            $('#imgInp').addClass("hidden");
            $('#imgInp').removeClass("required");
            $('#blah').addClass("hidden");

        }
    }
</script>

<div class="col col-sm-5">

    <label>Attachment </label>
    <select class="form-control" id="tagoan1" name="taguan" onchange="papeles()" required disabled>
        <option value="">With Attachment?</option>
        <option value="YES">Yes</option>
        <option value="NO">No</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group" style="margin:0;">
            <input type='file' name="image" id="imgInp" value="" class="hidden required btn btn-block btn-sm" style="padding-left:3em;width:300px"/>
        </div>
        <img id="blah" src="customer/tagoan/images/noimage.png"  height="200px" width="300px" name="tae" border-color="white" placeholder="" class="hidden"/>

    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
         function readURL(input) {

             if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                 var reader = new FileReader();

                 reader.onload = function (e) {
                     $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
                 }

                 reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
             }
         }

         $("#imgInp").change(function () {
             readURL(this);
         });

</script>
```

The problem is that when i click yes but i dont choose a file, the picture will still submit it should not submit because of the add class required   how to solve this.

Comment: You're not doing anything with the class `required` though? So what does it matter that it was added? If you want the field to be required is chosen then simply adding a class of required won't do that for you

Answer (score 0):

when you hide an input, it is not removed from the page. So, the file input stays in the form, and sumbitted regardless if it's hidden or not. What you need is to remove the input from DOM:

```
    if (x == "YES")
    {
        $('#imgInp').remove() // file input gone
        $('#blah').removeClass("hidden");
    } else
    {
        //you should add an ID to the parent of imgInp instead of referring as .form-group
        $('.form-group').prepend("<input type='file' name='image' id='imgInp' value='' class='required btn btn-block btn-sm' style='padding-left:3em;width:300px'/>")
        $('#blah').addClass("hidden");

    }
```

Comment: its okay now you can close the trend if you want, i already solve the problem, thanks for answering me.

Comment: you can approve the answer if it sounds helpful to you.

Comment: no offense but neither your answer nor the other solve the problem i just solve it by experimenting and using document.getelementByid

Answer (score 0):

is it okay if you just use `.hide()` and `.show()` of jQuery?

Comment: its okay now you can close the trend if you want, i already solve the problem, thanks for answering me.